# How to print JSON array with AJAX call in a pretty format for UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to validate data in a modal. If there is an error, an alert box is displayed. I am getting the output of the API in this format:

```
[{"Column":"ReportId","Result":"Invalid","Value":"repTest"}, 
{"Column":"Category","Result":"Invalid","Value":"testing"}]
```

I want to make it more readable to the user. How to get an output something like this in the alert box:

> ReportId is invalid due to repTest
>   Category is invalid due to testing    ( or any custom string between the corresponding values)

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validate_report',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(AddreportRepoFinalObj),
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.indexOf('Failure') > -1){
                var e=JSON.stringify(data);
                pwIsf.alert({msg:'Failure'+e ,type:'error'});   
            }
            else if(data.indexOf('Success')>-1) 
            {
                document.getElementById('btn_addUpdate').removeAttribute('disabled')
                pwIsf.alert({msg:'Valid',type:'info'}); 
                $(validAddRepbtn).off();      
            }
            else{
                var a=data;                            // I want to access the value part here from the data. Like I want to get rcaReportID, Invalid and repTest only and not column result and value
               pwIsf.alert({msg:a, type:'error'}); 
            }
        },


    })
```

Comment: kindly post expected output alos.

Comment: ReportId is invalid due to repTest
new line 
Category is invalid due to testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `data` in the final `if` condition in your example is a JSON string then you first need to parse it to an array of objects. From there you can loop through it and build your string output:

```js
let data = '[{"Column":"ReportId","Result":"Invalid","Value":"repTest"},{"Column":"Category","Result":"Invalid","Value":"testing"}]'
let arr = JSON.parse(data);
var message = arr.map(o => `${o.Column} is ${o.Result} due to ${o.Value}`).join('\r\n');

console.log(message);
```

Comment: I am able to print it in the desired format but its not changing the line. 2 different values are being seperated by a space:
"In exp1threshold The value is not according to the defined tunable parameter format. : 12 In exp2threshold The value cannot be purely alphabetical : awd "

Comment: It depends where you're outputting the values. If it's going in to an HTML element, try changing `'\r\n'` to `'<br />'`